# ajax request to php object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, oop

**EDIT: I SOLVED IT! (QUESTION 3)**
**now i only get the json object nad not the HTML anymore**
*I'll post my solution in a separate answer below, so its easier to understand what i did.*

**1.) Basic question:**
I'd like to know if it is possible to get the return value of a method in a php object via jquery ajax request.

In other words:
I try to get the return value of something like this:

```
$dbfunctions = new dbfunctions();
$dbfunctions->saveUser(); //<--- the return value of saveUser() is what i need, but in a result of an ajax request
```

**2.) Here is what i'm doing in my project:**
Its very simple - i just wanna check if an E-Mail already exists in my database and i do this with this saveUser() method of my $dbfunctions object:

**$dbfunctions:**

```
class dbfunctions {    
 //(...)    
  public function saveUser(array $datas) {

   //(...) preparing some variables for mysql query

    $sqlMail = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT `email` from `myTable` WHERE `email` = '" . $this->mysqli->escape_string($datas['email']) . "';");

    if ($sqlMail->num_rows) { //<--- check if mail exists in DB


      return false; //<-- this is what i need in the ajax result


    } else {
      $this->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`name`, `street`, `email`)
            VALUES('" .
              $this->mysqli->escape_string($datas['name']) . "','" .
              $this->mysqli->escape_string($datas['street']) . "','" .
              $this->mysqli->escape_string($datas['email'] . "');"
              // (...)
      );      
    }
  }
}
```

**$controller**

```
class controller {

  //constructor and preparing some variables (...)

  public function dbStuff() {
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != "") {

      require_once 'dbfunctions.php';
      $dbfunctions = new dbfunctions();

      //Save new User
      if ($_GET['action'] == 'newUser') {
        $entryDatas = array(
          'first_name' => trim($_POST['name']),            
          'street' => trim($_POST['street']),            
          'email' => trim($_POST['email']),
          //(...)            
      );


      //THIS IS WHAT I DID WITHOUT AJAX
      /*if ($dbfunctions->saveUser($entryDatas) === false) {
        header("Location: index.php?page=registerform&mail=exists");
        //in the registerform page a message is displayed via echo
        // "your mail already exists"
      } else {
        //everything is cool
        header("Location: index.php?page=confirmation?var=xyz);
      }*/

      /*+++ AND I CHANGED IT TO +++*/

      if ($dbfunctions->saveUser($entryDatas) === false) {          
      $res = array(
          "result" => false,
          "message" => "Email already exists"
      );
      echo json_encode($res);

      } else {
       $code = $dbfunctions->getOptinHash();
       $res = array(
          "result" => true,
          "message" => "Success"
      );
      echo json_encode($res);          

    }
    }    
  }
```

Thanks a lot.

If the Basic question "1.)" is "no", you can ignore "2.)"

EDIT:
+++ CHANGED CODE, GETTING STRANGE RESPONSE +++

Hello again,
thanks for your help - i changed code as you suggested using json_encode(see changes above near the "+++")

And added following JS-Code:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "index.php?action=newUser",
      type: "POST",
      data: $(registerform).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.result === true) {
          alert("success: " + response.message);
          // window.location = "..../index.php?page=confirmation?var=your_email"
        } else {
          alert("fail: " + response.message);
        }
      }
    });
```

I left the alerts inside to check the response.
The response.message is undefined.

But i didn't trust them so i checked the "response" only.
And it was good and bad too:

I got the deserved message at the beginning of the response, but after it, i get lots of HTML-Code:

```
{"result":false,"message":"Email already exists"}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
    <title>some title</title>    
    <meta name="language" content="de">
```

(.....)

and lots more.
I get the entire page HTML of my index page.

Maybe it has something to do with the small templatesystem i'm working with?
It is controlled by "page" parameter and a renderer object.

ike this in the constructor of the controller: `$this->renderer->setTemplate($this->pageVal);`

I think this is why im getting the entire html-code: is this possible?


**3.)


So another question is:**
Can i change the ajax request so i get only the result of

```
$dbfunctions->saveUser($entryDatas)
```

from the controller?

Comment: yes use json encoding

Comment: You can get the exact object using json_encode in your php file. Then parse it and use it like a normal jquery/javascript object!.

Comment: here the thing is how to call a controller's method by an ajax request. In case you have considered it already, then you can just do `$dbfunctions = new dbfunctions();
$savedUser = $dbfunctions->saveUser(); return json_encode($savedUser);`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answers! They will solve my problem.I forgot jason, hope he isn't angry at me now :)

Comment: Hi, i get the response i deserve. Thanks! But im getting the html of my rendering functions too, because the controller is part of a tiny self-made template-system. So the response contains the json-object and the HTML of the index page. See changes above. Thnks again!

Comment: ... i think the comment of "poncite" might bring me closer to my target(?)

Comment: `$savedUser = $dbfunctions->saveUser($entryDatas);
return json_encode($savedUser);` returns the HTML too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller;

```
if ($dbfunctions->saveUser($entryDatas) === false) {
    $res = array(
        "result" => false,
        "message" => "Email already exists"
    );
} else {
    $res = array(
        "result" => true,
        "message" => "Success"
    );
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

And in js,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your_url",
    type: "POST",
    data: "action=newUser&name=your_name&street=your_street&email=your_email",
    success: function(response) {
        if(response.result == true) {
            window.location = "..../index.php?page=confirmation?var=your_email"
        } else {
            alert(response.message);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Hüseyin for your detailled answer - i'll test it. Have a nice week.

Comment: Hey, when I add  dataType: 'json', in options of your ajax request it works fine - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my solution in i seperate answer - i hope this will help others with the same problem!

The Solution is to check if it is an ajax request or a "normal" request.
And if it's an ajax request, deaktivate the page rendering call in the constructor.

Thank you for your help again!
Have a nice day!

*If you leave comments to this first solution i'll read it and update the answer of course if needed.*

Here's the code:
**HTML REGISTER FORM**

```
//action is index.php?action=newUser
<form name="registerform" id="registerform" method="post" action="index.php?action=newUser" accept-charset="UTF-8">
//(...)
```

**javaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//(...)
$('#registerform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formAction = $(this).attr('action');
    //console.log('Sending request to ' + formAction + ' with data: '+$(this).serialize());
    validateRegisterForm();
  });
}

function validateRegisterForm() {
//doing some form validation(...)


//CHECK IF E-MAIL EXISTS  
  $.ajax({
    url: $(registerform).attr('action') + "&request=ajax", //<--this is the "check if request is an ajax request"
    type: "POST",
    data: $(registerform).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json', //<-- don't forget this or u will get undefined
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.result === true) {
        console.log("response result: " + response.result);
        // window.location = "..../index.php?page=confirmation?var=your_email"
      } else {
        console.log("response result: " + response.result);       
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**controller**

```
class controller {
  //(...) some variables
  public function __construct() {
  //(...) initializing the rendering stuff here

  //check if it's an ajax request
    if($this->ajaxRequest == false){
      $this->render->renderTemplate($page);
    }
  }

 //(...)


   if ($dbfunctions->saveUser($entryDatas) === false) {
      $res = array(
          "result" => false,
          "mail" => "Email already exists"
      );
      echo json_encode($res);          
    } else {
      $res = array(
          "result" => true,
          "message" => "Success"
      );
      echo json_encode($res);          
    }     
}
```

**THE RESPONSE should look like this**

```
//E-Mail is available
{"result":true,"message":"Success"}

//E-Mail already exists
{"result":false,"mail":"Email already exists"}
```